# API autodiscovery in Mule 4 for multiple flows

Tags: mule4, ibm-api-management, autodiscovery

i have 2 flows in my application and when i try to create API autodiscovery policy , we can only choose any one flow from drop down. How can we create API autodiscovery for both flows. Do we need to create 2 autodiscovery config each for one flow?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APTToolkit router should be used in this case which i was not using.

Answer (score 0):

Using more than one autodiscovery configuration per API is just not supported.

Comment: How can i apply the policy to second flow?

Comment: It is not supported and not expected to work. You should create a second API to set the autodiscovery for the second flow